# Why does the new keyword not create a unique instance of the Router class?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In this example why does the new keyword not create a unique instance of the Router class being used?  You can see that my simple router has a $deferred property, which gets resolved, but even when creating a new class and testing the state again, it is still resolved instead of being reset to "pending" when the new class is created.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    $deferred: new $.Deferred(),
    initialize: function () {

    }

});

var router1 = new Router({});
$("#results").append(router1.$deferred.state() + "<br>");  //pending
router1.$deferred.resolve();
$("#results").append(router1.$deferred.state() + "<br>"); // resolved

var router2 = new Router({});
$("#results").append(router2.$deferred.state() + "<br>"); //resolved -- should be pending
router2.$deferred.resolve();
$("#results").append(router2.$deferred.state() + "<br>"); //resolved
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nv7ep/

Comment: Because what you're doing adds the `$deferred` instance to the `Router`prototype, not an instance of the `Router` class. So, there's only one instance of the result of calling `new $.Deferred()` shared across all instances of `Router`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phoenecke/Nv7ep/1/

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        // add the deferred object to the new instance.
        this.$deferred = new $.Deferred();
    }

});
```

When you add the property like you were, in `extend`, it is added to the prototype, so `$deferred` is shared by all instances. If you want a unique instance of the deferred for each instance of the Router, you should add it in `initialize`.

Comment: Wow, this is great thanks! To clarify, when you use `extend` backbone updates the prototype of the class and then creates a new version from that updated prototype?

Comment: A new prototype is created for your 'class' and the properties you pass to `extend` are added to it.  There is one instance of that prototype created only when you call `extend`. That prototype object's prototype is Backbone.Router's prototype. So there is a chain of prototypes set up when you call `extend`.

Comment: You can see how that happens in the `extend` function near the bottom of the [backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js).